# Unable to create 9patch images

Tags: android, android-image

I created a `tab bar` with images. But in my emulator images are looking good. But while running apk **in mobile the tab bar images looking very small** in size. So I created `9patch images` from this http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html, I can place `xyz.9.png` image in my drawable folder but I can use setImageResource like  `img_home.setImageResource(R.drawable.footer_icon1);` But if i use xyz.9.png for image resource it displays me an error. Can I keep that 9.png like as same now? How can I fix my problem. Please help me

Comment: Please put error here, and which device you test this application?

Comment: can i diretly upload image and downlad zip from this link http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html ?

Answer (score 1):

If 9patch image name is `xyz.9.png` for setting image resource in `ImageView` or `ImageButton` you have to give only `image name` except `.9.png` portion like this

```
img_home.setImageResource(R.drawable.xyz);
```

Comment: i place like that only... but in my emulator even in large nd small size emulator also the tab bar images looks good.... but in mbile  it looks like small images

Comment: for that case don't use 9-patch image create image in different resolution and place those images in different drawable folders

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so 9 patch images will be a right choice here. You need to cut the tab bar icons for each DPI (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and so on) because emulator's resolution and DPI might be different than the device you are testing your app on. Take a look at Android's official guideline for icons - [Android iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

Its important to have icons for each DPI as it makes your app graphics look good and sharp throughout all the devices.

Hope it helps.